# MongoDB/Strongloop/Loopback - Offline syncro between devices with wifi without internet connection

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, couchbase, strongloop

I would like to know if it's possible to synchronized several devices by a wifi connection without internet connection.

For example, I have a mongodb/nodejs server on internet, and I use android/ios apps with the same wifi connection (to interact with database and an API). 
When my internet connection is down on my wifi, I would like to share (like peer to peer) a local database between devices to use apps without internet connection. And when internet connection is back on my wifi, all devices synchronize database with nodejs/mongodb.

I'm looking for a documentation or keywords to do this.

I found a way who works with couchbase (couchdb) and couchLite. But I'm interested to do this with mongodb.

Thanks

Comment: There is two questions. How to you manage P2P sync without internet? This usually involves a discovery method like mDNS. And then how do you sync a local db to Mongo, to which I have no answer.